# Getting Run-time error '3159': Not a valid bookmark while pulling SQL recordset

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, ms-access-forms

I am trying to populate `frmPanelUnitEntryHeader.txtJOB_NUMBER` and `.txtRELEASE_NUMBER` with a record based on `frmPackingSlipHeader.JOB` and `.REL` controls.  As records are navigated through on `frmPackingSlipHeader`, `.JOB` and `.REL` are committed to `gtxtCurrentJobNumber` & `gtxtCurrentJobRelease` global variables.  I came across the `rs.FindFirst` method but it takes about a minute or longer to come back with a valid record; the correct record is found and appears as expected.  After complain-searching about the long wait with `.FindFirst`, I came across the `OpenRecordset` method and use `strSQL` to pull the record but get the run-time error '3159' message on `Me.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark`.  `frmPanelUnitEntryHeader` is not a subfrom.

```
Private Sub txtJOB_NUMBER_GotFocus()

    'Used to bring up existing jobs in SUB table
    Dim rs      As Object
    Dim strSQL  As String

'    Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM MAIN_SUB WHERE [JOB_NUMBER] = '" & gtxtCurrentJobNumber & "' And RELEASE_NUMBER = '" & gtxtCurrentJobRelease & "';"
    
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
    
    With rs
        If .RecordCount = 0 Then
            DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
        Else
            Me.Bookmark = .Bookmark
        End If
    End With

    Set rs = Nothing
            

'    With rs
'        .FindFirst "JOB_NUMBER='" & gtxtCurrentJobNumber & "' And RELEASE_NUMBER='" & gtxtCurrentJobRelease & "'"
'        If .NoMatch Then
'            DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
'        Else
'            Me.Bookmark = .Bookmark
'        End If
'    End With
'
'    Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```

The commented lines go together.

I noticed while searching on the error that many sites resort to database corruption and repair but I do not believe that to be the case here.  The `.FindFirst` works, but slowly.  Why do bookmarks seem to work differently between the two methods?  Does it have anything to do with the fact that I am doing this on `txtJOB_NUMBER_GotFocus()`?  TIA.

Comment: Warning, this is **wide** open to injection. You need to parametrise your queries.#

Comment: ADO allows using parameterised queries.

Comment: Why am I getting dinged with a -1?

Comment: Downvotes, on questions, are meant to show that the person that did the downvote believes your question is either unhelpful or lacks research, @Tim . I cannot comment on which of those that they believe is true (only the downvoter can tell you that, and they are not required to comment to downvote).

Answer (score 0):

If you read the docs on [Form.Bookmark](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.form.bookmark) carefully it says:

> Because Access creates a unique bookmark for each record in a form's recordset when a form is opened, a form's bookmark will not work on another recordset, even when the two recordsets are based on the same table, query, or SQL statement.

So each recordset has different bookmarks and you can only use bookmarks from the same recordset.

A `.RecordsetClone` is the same recordset but a different cursor, that's why `Me.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark`works if `rs` is a clone of `Me.Recordset` (and fails if not like `rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)`).

You may try filter the recordset directly with:

```vb
Private Sub txtJOB_NUMBER_GotFocus()
    With CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef(vbNullString) 'Temporary QueryDef to use parameters
        .SQL = "SELECT * FROM MAIN_SUB  WHERE [JOB_NUMBER] = [CurrentJobNumberParameter] And RELEASE_NUMBER = [CurrentJobReleaseParameter];"
        .Parameters("CurrentJobNumberParameter") = gtxtCurrentJobNumber
        .Parameters("CurrentJobReleaseParameter") = gtxtCurrentJobRelease
        With .OpenRecordset
            If .RecordCount = 0 Then
                Me.Recordset.NewRecord
            Else
                Set Me.Recordset = .Parent.Recordsets(.Name) ' equvalent to Set Me.Recordset = rs, but without the need of variables declaration
            End If
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

This code also shows how to avoid injections with parameters on DAO. Read [Bobby Tables](https://bobby-tables.com/) and its [Microsoft Access](https://bobby-tables.com/msaccess) section!

Comment: Thanks ComputerVersteher, implemented.  However, upon operation, the user is prompted for both parameters.  Is that by design?

Comment: OK...  Not sure why it is prompting.  When I step through with a breakpoint on the first With, the code steps through and returns the expected recordset without prompts.  When I don't step through, the prompts both come up.  Oh, and by the way ComputerVersteher, the code is instantaneous, when it doesn't prompt, so thanks for that.

Comment: Maybe problems in your functions `gtxtCurrentJobNumber` and `gtxtCurrentJobRelease`? Replace them with static values. If no prompt then show code of them in question.

Comment: Your code is slow because you first fetch a lot of data from sql server and then you filter that on the ms access client, without being able to use indexes. My code filters on the sql server and only fetches the small result data.